# git blame ignore whitespace option buggy?

Tags: git, blame, git-blame

Based on my understanding, the command [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) is supposed to show, for each line in a file, the author and the commit in which the line was last modified. So for example, if I run `git blame -- "<filename>"` and get the following output for line 5:

```
106b77db (Walrus 2016-03-24 10:01:36 +0800   5) .root {
```

it means the line `.root {` originated from the author `Walrus` in the commit `106b77db`. In other words, if I inspect the patch produced by `106b77db` using `git show -p 106b77db`, I would expect the line `+.root {` to show up in the diff. Indeed, this is the case.

Snippet from `106b77db`'s diff for `<filename>`:

```
 /* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule       which uses -fx-Property */
+.root {
+   -fx-background-color: transparent;
+}
+
```

Now, when I run `git blame -w -- "<filename>"`, (the [`-w`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#git-blame--w) option ignores whitespace changes, i.e. traces each line backwards in time to find the last author which introduced **non**-whitespace changes to that line), I now get the following output for line 5:

```
b6a6e8a2 (Walrus 2016-03-31 23:32:50 +0800   5) .root {
```

However, when I inspect the patch for `b6a6e8a2` using `git show -p b6a6e8a2`, the diff shows `.root {` rather than `+.root {` as expected.

Snippet from `b6a6e8a2`'s diff for `<filename>`:

```
+
+/* setting window to be transparent================================ */
 .root {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
-}
-
```

Has Git given me erroneous output, because according to the diff, the line `.root {` was not modified at all in the commit `b6a6e8a2`?

I am using Git 2.13.3.windows.1.

EDIT: the repository is https://github.com/cs2103jan2016-f14-2j/main, and the file is `JimplePlanner/src/application.css`. After upgrading to Git 2.16.1.windows.4, the issue still persists.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in simple tests, so you'll probably need to give more specific information. Instead of *describing* the commands you issued and the results, you should show the exact command as it was typed and the exact output as it was printed.

Comment: ...or better yet, either link to the repository in question or set up a reproducible example to which we can have access.

Comment: @larsks Added the full commands, relevant output snippets, the repository link and filename. I did not show the full output as it is hundreds of lines long, and most of it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Updated. Could not tag you and larsks in the same comment.

Comment: Can anyone at least verify that this example is reproducible on their machine?

Comment: Bump, hope someone is willing and able to help.

Answer (score 1):

five years later I encountered the same issue and floundered in trying to understand what happened.

It turned out that when you ignore whitespace, git sometimes understands the change to have been a completely different one, because of a repeating pattern that, after whitespace elision, changes the location of the detected "smallest change".

Running `git diff -w` vs `git diff` on the "incorrect" revision (in your case, `b6a6e8a`) illustrates the problem:

`git diff b6a6e8a~..b6a6e8a`:

```
diff --git a/JimplePlanner/src/application.css b/JimplePlanner/src/application.css
index e4634ef..c0cc44b 100644
--- a/JimplePlanner/src/application.css
+++ b/JimplePlanner/src/application.css
@@ -1,248 +1,108 @@
 /* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */
+
+/* setting window to be transparent================================ */
 .root {
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
-}
-
-.today-pane {
```

`git diff -w b6a6e8a~..b6a6e8a`:

```
diff --git a/JimplePlanner/src/application.css b/JimplePlanner/src/application.css
index e4634ef..c0cc44b 100644
--- a/JimplePlanner/src/application.css
+++ b/JimplePlanner/src/application.css
@@ -1,248 +1,108 @@
 /* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */
-.root {
-       -fx-background-color: transparent;
-}
-
-.today-pane {
-       -fx-background-radius: 10px;
-    -fx-background-color: white;
-    -fx-border-color: grey;
-    -fx-border-radius: 10px;
-}
-
-.list-view {
-    -fx-padding: 3px ;
-    -fx-background-color: transparent;
-}
-
- .list-cell {
-    -fx-padding: 10px ;
-    -fx-background-color: transparent, -fx-background ;
-}

-
-.list-cell:empty {
-    -fx-padding: 10px;
+/* setting window to be transparent================================ */
+.root {
        -fx-background-color: transparent;
-    -fx-background-insets: 0 ;
-}
+}/*============================================++================== */
```

When whitespace is ignored, the diff algorithm ends up counting `.root {` as removed in one place, and added back in a different place.

This is just a consequence of ignoring whitespace - it will sometimes interpret changes that were made substantially differently to how you think about them; more often than when not ignoring whitespace.